# "I don't like all/every X": does it mean I only like some X, or I like no X?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> I don't like all students

Does it mean I like some students or none?

> I don't like every student

Does it mean I like some students or none?

I have always been bothered by these questions, and whenever I use them, no one seems to have an issue. That means, I could have been misunderstood all the time. Can some knowledgeable person shed some light on this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Everything is not as it seems](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50505/everything-is-not/50513#50513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Everything is not…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50505/everything-is-not)

Comment: The answer to your question is ***yes***.

Comment: This question is not a dup of the earlier q. It is true that answering each  question involves understanding a sentence with a negative and a quantifier. However, the positions of negative and quantifier in this q are different from the earlier q. So the earlier q's answers don't answer this q.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't like all students" means that it is not true that I like all students. This means something similar to "I dislike some students".

"I don't like every student" is similar. It means that it is not true that I like every student.